# Python - RuntimeError: working outside of request context

Tags: python

Trying to get the GET parameters from the URL. I have it working in my `__init__.py` file, but in a different file its not working.

I tried to use `with app.app_context():` but I am still getting the same issue.

```
def log_entry(entity, type, entity_id, data, error):
    with app.app_context():
        zip_id = request.args.get('id')
```

RuntimeError: working outside of request context

Any suggestions?

Additional Info:

- This is using Flask web framework which is setup as a service (API).
- Example URL the user would hit http://website.com/api/endpoint?id=1
- As mentioned above using `zip_id = request.args.get('id') works fine in the main file but I am in runners.py (just another file with definitions in)
- Full traceback:

`Debugging middleware caught exception in streamed response at a point where response headers were already sent.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ereeve/.virtualenvs/pi-automation-api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 703, in __next__
    return self._next()
  File "/Users/ereeve/.virtualenvs/pi-automation-api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 81, in _iter_encoded
    for item in iterable:
  File "/Users/ereeve/Documents/TechSol/pi-automation-api/automation_api/runners.py", line 341, in create_agencies
    log_entry("test", "created", 1, "{'data':'hey'}", "")
  File "/Users/ereeve/Documents/TechSol/pi-automation-api/automation_api/runners.py", line 315, in log_entry
    zip_id = request.args.get('id')
  File "/Users/ereeve/.virtualenvs/pi-automation-api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 343, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "/Users/ereeve/.virtualenvs/pi-automation-api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 302, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "/Users/ereeve/.virtualenvs/pi-automation-api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/globals.py", line 20, in _lookup_req_object
    raise RuntimeError('working outside of request context')
RuntimeError: working outside of request context`

Def in the same file calling the log_entry def

```
def create_agencies(country_code, DB, session):
    document = DB.find_one({'rb_account_id': RB_COUNTRIES_new[country_code]['rb_account_id']})
    t2 = new_t2(session)

    log_entry("test", "created", 1, "{'data':'hey'}", "")
```

Comment: No because this is completely lacking any relevant information. What "URL"? Presumably this is some kind of web framework, but you haven't told us which one. What app context? What "different file" are you in? Are you actually in the middle of some code that responds to URLs, and if so why don't you post the rest of it? And why don't you post the full error and traceback?

Comment: @DanielRoseman added extra info. Hopefully this will help :)

Comment: Not really, I'm afraid. You still need to show how you're calling `log_entry` and where from.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Added.

Comment: Thanks but you're still not showing the full picture. How is all this related to the code that handles the URL?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Dont worry - ill work it out myself. You obviously haven't experienced the issue before and don't have any understanding of the problem. Thanks for your help.